# How to Remove 404 AMP pages from Google search Console for wordpress AMP plugin

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

For my website in Google search console I am getting 404 AMP pages issue. And I am unable to delete those from Google search console.How to permantatly delete those 404 from Google search console. Suggest me answer for this.

I have removed AMP plugin from my wordpress backend.